# Is it possible to create a nested route in react router which is not a sub route of the parent?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In my react project I have a route which has multiple routes inside of it

```
<Route path="/journeys/journey1" component={Journey1} />
```

inside the Journey1 component I have multiple different routes

```
class Joureny1 extends React.component {
      ...
      return (
                <Switch>
                  <Route
                    path={`/terms`} 
                    render={...}
                  />
                  ...
                    <Route component={PageNotFound} />
                </Switch>
            );
    }
```

Is it possible for the terms route to point to `url/terms` instead if `url/journeys/journey1/terms`?

Comment: I'm guessing `/terms` should do the trick. (a relative URL starting with a `/` indicates it's supposed to be appended to the host, not the current location. not sure if RR supports that here though)

Comment: But that's the wrong use of routing. If you need to route from the component, use `Link` available in react-router

Comment: @ChrisG im trying `/terms` but the page not found is showing

Comment: @SabaHassan <Link /> is used for navigation, i am not creating a button, im creating a route

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your goal is here. Here's what a `<Route>` does: `Its most basic responsibility is to render some UI when its path matches the current URL.` A route doesn't *point* anywhere.

Comment: If you want the route as url/terms, then the Route should be outside of journey Component.

Comment: why ? if `terms` does not belong to `journey1` then you should put it in the outer routes. If it **does** belong to `journey1` then it should be at `/journey1/terms`